# FMS on windows azure

Tags: azure, flash-media-server

I have an application that uses fms and i want to upload to windows azure, my question is:

Can i install Flash Media Server on Windows Azure? and if yes how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is it, a windows service? Does it have a silent install?

Comment: Flash Media Server is a data and media server from Adobe. I think that no silent installation.

Comment: You'll probably need to use a VM Role then. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433107.aspx

Comment: I apply for acces to beta program to test this, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Richard say, the solution is use Windows Azure VM Role